# $dataProvider для MANY_MANY

Tags: php, yii

Здравствуйте, Прошу помощи, сам запутался

Есть модели `Category`, `Products` и `ProductsInCategories`

**modeles/Category.php**

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
         'products' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Products', 'products_in_categories(categories_id, products_id)'),
    );
}
```

**views/category/view.php**

```
    foreach($model->products as $product)
        $this->renderPartial('/products/item', array('data' => $product));
```

Таким образом я вывожу все необходимые мне данные, но тут понадобилась пагинация сортировка и тд.. Вопрос в Следующем, как в эту конструкцию вживить `CActiveDataProvider` ну и дальше я соответственно передаю его в `CListView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//в модели Products
public $categoryId = null;

//в массив, возвращаемый функцией rules добавить
array('categoryId', 'safe')

public function relations()
{
  return array(
    'productInCategory'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ProductCategories', array('id'=>'products_id')),
    'category'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Category', array('categories_id'=>'id'), 'through'=>'productsInCategory'),
  );
}

//это в какую-нибудь функцию в модели Products
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->compare('category.id', $this->categoryId);
return new CActiveDataProvider('Products',array(
  'criteria'=>$criteria,
  'sort'=>array(
     'defaultOrder'=>'id',
     'attributes'=>array(
        'id'=>array(
          'asc'=>$field='id',
          'desc'=>$field.' DESC',
        ),
     ),
  ),
));

// во вьюшке
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView',array(
  'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
  'itemView'=>'_item_product'
));
```

Comment: а с контроллера как вызывать?

Comment: Код с ActiveDataProvider засовываете в какую-нибудь функцию в модели.
В контроллере вызываете:
 $model->categoryId = 1; // id категории, которая нужна
 $dataProvider = $model->someFunction().
Во вьюшку передаете $dataProvider

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category.id' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `products` `t` WHERE category.id=:ycp0

Странно, реляцию прописал а найти колону не может

Comment: добавил $criteria->with = array('category'); вроде заработало

Comment: Да, действительно надо было добавить. Забыл про это.